# Nested property keys not working with custom template

Tags: angularjs, x-editable, angular-formly

Nested property keys is working fine with default type. But it's not working with the below custom template. Why ?

Here is my fields:

```
 vm.fields = [
      {
        type: 'editableInput',
        key: 'profile.name.firstname',
        templateOptions: {
          label: 'First Name'
        }
      },
     {
        type: 'editableInput',
        key: 'profile.name.lastname',
        templateOptions: {
          label: 'Last Name'
        }
      }
    ];
```

What I expected :

```
{
  "profile": {
    "name": {
      "firstname": "rajagopal",
      "lastname": "subramanian"
    }
 }
```

But this is what I get:

```
 {
    "profile.name.firstname": "rajagopal",
     "profile.name.lastname": "subramanian"
 }
```

My Formly Config:

```
 formlyConfig.setType({
      extends: 'input',
      template: '<div><span editable-text="model[options.key]" e-name="{{::id}}"}}">{{ model[options.key] || "empty" }}</span></div>',
      name: 'editableInput'
    });
```

Here is [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/vovila/edit?html,js,output)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Aren't those two identical other than structure?

Comment: yaa may be.  I just want to acheive this  http://angular-formly.com/#/example/advanced/nested-property-keys  with custom template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with [how nested keys work](https://github.com/formly-js/angular-formly/blob/v7.3.2/src/run/formlyNgModelAttrsManipulator.js#L46-L50) with angular-formly. Basically it only works with elements that have an `ng-model`.  The work around for you is to use the `model` property, and not nested keys (like [this](https://jsbin.com/buxowa/edit?html,js,output)):

```
{
  type: 'editableInput',
  model: 'model.profile.name',
  key: 'firstname',
  templateOptions: {
    label: 'First Name',
    placeholder: 'Enter your First Name'
  }
},
{
  type: 'editableInput',
  model: 'model.profile.name',
  key: 'lastname',
  templateOptions: {
    label: 'Last Name',
    placeholder: 'Enter your First Name'
  }
}
```

Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

```
profile.name.firstname - > profile[name][firstname]
```

It's my imagine.I have never used Angular